# getting values between layers of a neural network using functional API

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network, data-science

I am using below simple neural network for classification

```
model2 = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(X.shape[1], X.shape[2])),
    keras.layers.Dense(64, activation ='relu'),
       
    keras.layers.Dense(32, activation ='relu'),
    
    keras.layers.Dense(16, activation ='relu'),
       
    keras.layers.Dense(5, activation ='softmax')
])
```

I would like to check how the values for different classes change after going through each layer using the Euclidean distance to see which layer is the most useful and which is the least.
Does it make sense? If so, how can I do it using functional API? I encountered the first problems at the very beginning - they are related to the shape of the data - originally it is (1991, 13, 1292).

Comment: What would you compare the values of a middle layer with?this is why the loss function is applied on the output of the model

Comment: I would like to compare the distances of objects belonging to the same classes to check whether they are distant or closer to each other, but I do not know if it is feasible at all? If not, is there any other way to check the usability of each layer?

Comment: Instead of using the Keras API, you can create a NN using the low-level ops. Create the parameters using the `tf.Variable` and perform matrix multiplication with `tf.matmul`. By doing this, you'll have more control on the information which flows across the `Dense` layer.